# Loading maze from txt file

Tags: c++

Hello Im trying to load my maze from the txt file it has made but when im trying to load it from the same file the program only reads the value 1 which is my wall like this picture:

Comment: You are attempting to load an entire file into a single integer value?  I don't think that will do what you want.  How does the value get from `value` to `maze` ?

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger and it will be obvious what is happening.

Comment: dont remove the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the line:

```
readFile >> value;
```

The stream reads in ONLY the first integer, not the entire line/file content.
Thus in the following nested for-loop, every cell in `initialMaze` replicates the value.
Consider reading the value from the file, inside the nested for-loop.

```
for (int row(0); row < SIZEY; ++row){
for (int col(0); col < SIZEX; ++col)
{
    readFile >> initialMaze[row][col];
}
}
```